# How to open a process and read the results into an ifstream from within a C++ program?

Tags: c++, c++11, process, fstream, ifstream

I am writing a C++11 program that will run in a Unix environment (portability isn't a concern). Currently, I have a Makefile that invokes two processes, one which writes to a file and the second which reads from that file.

`target:
      mkfifo myfile
      other_program > myfile &
      my_program myfile`

For various reasons, I want invoke all of this from within my_program. It looks like `popen` is promising, as it invokes an external process and provides a FILE* I can read.  However, the existing file processing code I've already written uses ifstream:

`std::ifstream stream1(argv[1]);`

Is there a decent way to connect `popen`'s FILE* to an ifstream?  Is there something else I should use instead of `popen`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a stream buffer which reads from a `FILE*`. Clearly, you may need to change your code to use `std::istream` in case you use `std::ifstream` in other places than creating the stream but this should be a straight forward change. Here is a simple demo showing how to create a corresponding stream buffer and how to use it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

struct FILEbuf
    : std::streambuf {
    FILEbuf(FILE* fp): fp_(fp) {}
    int underflow() {
        if (this->gptr() == this->egptr()) {
            int size = fread(this->buffer_, 1, int(s_size), this->fp_);
            if (0 < size) {
                this->setg(this->buffer_, this->buffer_, this->buffer_ + size);
            }
        }
        return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
            ? traits_type::eof()
            : traits_type::to_int_type(*gptr());
     }
     FILE* fp_;
     enum { s_size = 1024 };
     char  buffer_[s_size];
};

int main()
{
    FILEbuf      sbuf(popen("ls -l", "r"));
    std::istream in(&sbuf);
    for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); ) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

In the past I have been told off for using `popen()` or `system()` because these calls are considered to be unsafe: both of these calls spawn a shell which can be used to hijack their behavior. The alternative is to create a stream buffer using file descriptors and using `pipe()`, `dup()` (or one of its siblings), `close()`, `fork()`, and `execl()` (or one of its siblings) to build the pipe directly.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Although I'm not going to pretend to understand some of the functions/members you implemented as part of the FILEbuf struct. Is there a reason s_size is 1024?

Comment: @Chris: 1024 is the size of the internal buffer. If you expect to get little data you can make it smaller; if you expect large amounts of data you can make it bigger. I guess it won't make much of a difference, though.

Comment: shouldn't it have `~FILEbuf() { if (fp_) { pclose(fp_); } }` ?

Comment: @truf Maybe. If you want to use it with existing file objects, e.g., `stdin` it isn't clear, though. The primary purpose was to how to create a simple stream buffer using a `FILE`. Whether that should take ownership or not is kind of an orthogonal decision.